# C compiler errors: conflicting types, incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Tags: c

i am having trouble compiling my tldlist.c file.

How do i tackle these issues:

- implicit declaration
- conflicting types
- incompatible integer to pointer conversion
- static declaration follows non-static declaration

Please ignore unused variable/parameter warnings. I still have not implemented some of the methods.

**Note: tldlist.h can't be modified in any way.**

Compiler errors:

```
bash-3.2$ gcc -c -W -Wall tldlist.c
tldlist.c:86:21: warning: implicit declaration of function 'tldnode_create' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    TLDNode *node = tldnode_create(tld_name);
                    ^
tldlist.c:86:14: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'TLDNode *' (aka 'struct tldnode *') with an expression of
      type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    TLDNode *node = tldnode_create(tld_name);
             ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tldlist.c:92:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'tldlist_add_node' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (!tldlist_add_node(tld, tld_name, tld->root))
         ^
tldlist.c:71:7: warning: unused variable 'comparison' [-Wunused-variable]
  int comparison;
      ^
tldlist.c:110:12: error: static declaration of 'tldlist_add_node' follows non-static declaration
static int tldlist_add_node(TLDList *tld, char *tld_name, TLDNode *node) {
           ^
tldlist.c:92:10: note: previous implicit declaration is here
    if (!tldlist_add_node(tld, tld_name, tld->root))
         ^
tldlist.c:121:14: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'TLDNode *' (aka 'struct tldnode *') with an expression of
      type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    TLDNode *new = tldnode_create(tld_name);
             ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tldlist.c:128:14: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'TLDNode *' (aka 'struct tldnode *') with an expression of
      type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    TLDNode *new = tldnode_create(tld_name);
             ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tldlist.c:151:43: warning: unused parameter 'tld' [-Wunused-parameter]
TLDIterator *tldlist_iter_create(TLDList *tld) {
                                          ^
tldlist.c:159:41: warning: unused parameter 'iter' [-Wunused-parameter]
TLDNode *tldlist_iter_next(TLDIterator *iter) {
                                        ^
tldlist.c:174:10: error: conflicting types for 'tldnode_create'
TLDNode *tldnode_create(char *element) {
         ^
tldlist.c:86:21: note: previous implicit declaration is here
    TLDNode *node = tldnode_create(tld_name);
                    ^
8 warnings and 2 errors generated.
```

tldlist.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "date.h"
#include "tldlist.h"

struct tldlist {
  struct tldnode *root;
  long count;
  long size;
  Date *begin;
  Date *end;
};

/*
 * TODO: check the definition of element. 
 */
struct tldnode {
  struct tldnode *parent;
  struct tldnode *left;
  struct tldnode *right;
  char *element;
  long count;
};

/*
 * TODO: look at lecture slides
 */
struct tlditerator {
  struct tldlist *tld;
};

/*
 * tldlist_create generates a list structure for storing counts against
 * top level domains (TLDs)
 *
 * creates a TLDList that is constrained to the `begin' and `end' Date's
 * returns a pointer to the list if successful, NULL if not
 */
TLDList *tldlist_create(Date *begin, Date *end) {
  TLDList *tldl = (TLDList *)malloc(sizeof(TLDList));

  if (tldl != NULL) {
    tldl->root = NULL;
    tldl->count = 0;
    tldl->begin = date_duplicate(begin);
    tldl->end = date_duplicate(end);
  }
  return tldl;
};

/*
 * tldlist_destroy destroys the list structure in `tld'
 *
 * all heap allocated storage associated with the list is returned to the heap
 */
void tldlist_destroy(TLDList *tld) {
  if (tld != NULL)
    free(tld);
};

/*
 * tldlist_add adds the TLD contained in `hostname' to the tldlist if
 * `d' falls in the begin and end dates associated with the list;
 * returns 1 if the entry was counted, 0 if not
 */
int tldlist_add(TLDList *tld, char *hostname, Date *d) {
  char *tld_capture;
  char *tld_name;
  int tld_length;
  int comparison;

  // check if 'd' in the date range
  if (date_compare(tld->begin, d) > 0 || date_compare(tld->end, d) < 0)
    return 0;

  // get TLD from hostname
  tld_capture = strrchr(hostname, '.') + 1;
  tld_length = strlen(tld_capture);
  tld_name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tld_length+1));
  tld_name[tld_length] = '\0';
  strcpy(tld_name, tld_capture);

  if (tld->root == NULL) {
    /* insert at root */
    TLDNode *node = tldnode_create(tld_name);
    node->count++;
    tld->root = node;
    tld->size++;
  } else {
    /* add elsewhere  */
    if (!tldlist_add_node(tld, tld_name, tld->root))
      free(tld_name);
    else
      tld->size++;
  }

  return 0;
};

/*
 * insert the TLD to the tree
 * consider 5 different cases:
 * (1) TLD name < current and there is a left node
 * (2) TLD name > current and there is a right node
 * (3) TLD name < current and there is no left node
 * (4) TLD name > current and there is no right node
 * (5) TLD name is equal to current
 */
static int tldlist_add_node(TLDList *tld, char *tld_name, TLDNode *node) {
  int comparison = strcmp(tld_name, node->element);

  if ((comparison < 0) && (node->left != NULL))
    /* case 1 */
    return tldlist_add_node(tld, tld_name, node->left);
  else if ((comparison > 0) && (node->right != NULL))
    /* case 2 */
    return tldlist_add_node(tld, tld_name, node->right);
  else if ((comparison < 0) && (node->left == NULL)) {
    /* case 3 */
    TLDNode *new = tldnode_create(tld_name);
    new->parent = node;
    new->count++;
    node->left = new;
    return 1;
  } else if ((comparison > 0) && (node->right == NULL)) {
    /* case 4 */
    TLDNode *new = tldnode_create(tld_name);
    new->parent = node;
    new->count++;
    node->right = new;
    return 1;
  } else {
    /* case 5 */
    node->count++;
    return 0;
  }
}
/*
 * tldlist_count returns the number of successful tldlist_add() calls since
 * the creation of the TLDList
 */
long tldlist_count(TLDList *tld) {
  return tld->count;
};

/*
 * tldlist_iter_create creates an iterator over the TLDList; returns a pointer
 * to the iterator if successful, NULL if not
 */
TLDIterator *tldlist_iter_create(TLDList *tld) {
  return NULL;
};

/*
 * tldlist_iter_next returns the next element in the list; returns a pointer
 * to the TLDNode if successful, NULL if no more elements to return
 */
TLDNode *tldlist_iter_next(TLDIterator *iter) {
  return NULL;
};

/*
 * tldlist_iter_destroy destroys the iterator specified by `iter'
 */
void tldlist_iter_destroy(TLDIterator *iter) {
  free(iter);
};

/*
 * tldnode_create() creates a new node that contains a TLD name
 * returns a pointer to the node if successful, NULL if not
 */
TLDNode *tldnode_create(char *element) {
  TLDNode *node = (TLDNode *)malloc(sizeof(TLDNode));

  if (node != NULL) {
    node->parent = NULL;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->count = 0;
  }
  return node;
}

/*
 * tldnode_tldname returns the tld associated with the TLDNode
 */
char *tldnode_tldname(TLDNode *node) {
  return node->element;
};

/*
 * tldnode_count returns the number of times that a log entry for the
 * corresponding tld was added to the list
 */
long tldnode_count(TLDNode *node) {
  return node->count;
};
```

tldlist.h:

```
#ifndef _TLDLIST_H_INCLUDED_
#define _TLDLIST_H_INCLUDED_

#include "date.h"

typedef struct tldlist TLDList;
typedef struct tldnode TLDNode;
typedef struct tlditerator TLDIterator;

/*
 * tldlist_create generates a list structure for storing counts against
 * top level domains (TLDs)
 *
 * creates a TLDList that is constrained to the `begin' and `end' Date's
 * returns a pointer to the list if successful, NULL if not
 */
TLDList *tldlist_create(Date *begin, Date *end);

/*
 * tldlist_destroy destroys the list structure in `tld'
 *
 * all heap allocated storage associated with the list is returned to the heap
 */
void tldlist_destroy(TLDList *tld);

/*
 * tldlist_add adds the TLD contained in `hostname' to the tldlist if
 * `d' falls in the begin and end dates associated with the list;
 * returns 1 if the entry was counted, 0 if not
 */
int tldlist_add(TLDList *tld, char *hostname, Date *d);

/*
 * tldlist_count returns the number of successful tldlist_add() calls since
 * the creation of the TLDList
 */
long tldlist_count(TLDList *tld);

/*
 * tldlist_iter_create creates an iterator over the TLDList; returns a pointer
 * to the iterator if successful, NULL if not
 */
TLDIterator *tldlist_iter_create(TLDList *tld);

/*
 * tldlist_iter_next returns the next element in the list; returns a pointer
 * to the TLDNode if successful, NULL if no more elements to return
 */
TLDNode *tldlist_iter_next(TLDIterator *iter);

/*
 * tldlist_iter_destroy destroys the iterator specified by `iter'
 */
void tldlist_iter_destroy(TLDIterator *iter);

/*
 * tldnode_tldname returns the tld associated with the TLDNode
 */
char *tldnode_tldname(TLDNode *node);

/*
 * tldnode_count returns the number of times that a log entry for the
 * corresponding tld was added to the list
 */
long tldnode_count(TLDNode *node);

#endif /* _TLDLIST_H_INCLUDED_ */
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if the code you posted followed [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: implicit declaration - just declare it...

Comment: @kfsone everything is fine with date.h.

Comment: @crashmstr The code is easy to read and all needed information is provided.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath please be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These errors are caused by missing prototypes - functions that you call in tldlist.c which the compiler has not yet seen a definition for.

By default the compiler assumes any unknown function returns int (legacy throwback to very early C where you could leave the return type out if it was going to be int). This is why you get the incompatible type messages :)

You need to provide the compiler with declarations of the functions. You could do this either by adding prototype stubs at the top of tldlist.c or by creating a tldnode.h which defines them (since it seems to be mostly node related functions you are missing).

The implementation for tldnode_create is

```
TLDNode *tldnode_create(char *element) {
```

So you need to declare

```
TLDNode *tldnode_create(char *element);
```

before you try to use it: either to tldnode.h or somewhere at the top of tldlist.c, e.g. after the delcaration of the tldnode struct.

```
/*
 * TODO: check the definition of element. 
 */
struct tldnode {
  struct tldnode *parent;
  struct tldnode *left;
  struct tldnode *right;
  char *element;
  long count;
};

TLDNode *tldnode_create(char *element);
```

Comment: The incompatible type warnings were the result of the default return type for an unknown function being "int" - this is a throw back to the early days of C when you only had to specify return type if it wasn't int. It was valid to write: `puts(char*); main() { puts("Hello world!"); }` as an entire program.

Answer (score 1):

Starting at top:
Your first warning is implicit declaration of function 'tldnode_create'.
You should define this function prototype in your .h file.
Given that you can't modify it, you should put a prototype at the  top of your .c file

This creates cascading errors, since the compiler is trying to be helpful by defining a default prototype which returns an integer (hence your next warning) about incompatible integer to pointer conversion.

Also, why are declaring the function static?

Comment: Please read the problem description. The .h file can't be altered in any way. What could be way around this? P.S. I am declaring the function static because it is part of the Binary Search Tree insertion algorithm. Have a look at the code.

Comment: @Foon Why not static? If it isn't used outside this C file, it is best if declared static. IMO, it should have been the default at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling functions that aren't defined in your header file, or your c file (before they're called.)  Look through.  tldnode_create isn't declared anywhere.  Nor is the add function.

Same is the issue for all your errors from what I can see.

Declare the functions before using them.